# Exclude nested properties from binding - [Bind(Exclude="SomeProperty")]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple ViewModel as given below

```
[Bind(Exclude = "State")]
public class CityViewModel {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}
```

The City property has a navigation reference to "State" Entity. In my view I am trying to add a new City, using the CityViewModel above. When adding city, I want the MVC to neglect the "City.State" property, so that it will not be bound and validated. So I use the `[Bind(Exclude = "State")]` on my CityViewModel. Surprisingly, in the controller, I get a model error for the "City.State" field (which I am trying to exclude from bind and validation).

How do I tell the MVC to neglect "City.State" property from binding and validation?

Edit: I have also tried `[Bind(Exclude = "City.State")]` but doesn't work. I still get `Model.IsValid` false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation is a separate step from the binding and will always work with all properties of the model, so bind exclude would not prevent from validation of the City.State

You can call

```
ModelState["City.State"].Errors.Clear();
```

before checking `Model.IsValid`.

P.S. I would preffer to add another viewmodel class with correct set of properties then using workaround I mentioned above.